# Show 1 phone attribute for each company when they have more than 1 phone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem, I need to show 1 phone for each company but I don't know how to do it

```
create table EntidadPublica
(
  nombreE varchar (20) not null unique,
  direccion varchar (50) null,
  primary key (nombreE)
)
go

create table Telefono
(
  nombreE varchar (20) not null,
  telefono varchar(9) not null,
  primary key (nombreE,telefono),
  foreign key (nombreE) references EntidadPublica (nombreE)
)   
go

Insert into EntidadPublica (nombreE, direccion) values('UTE', 'Ejido 1338')
Insert into EntidadPublica (nombreE, direccion) values('OSE', 'Casa Facundo')

insert into Telefono(nombreE, telefono) values('UTE', 22222222)
insert into Telefono(nombreE, telefono) values('UTE', 33333333)
insert into Telefono(nombreE, telefono) values('OSE', 44444444)
insert into Telefono(nombreE, telefono) values('OSE', 55555555)
```

I do this but I need to show 1 phone per company

```
select E.nombreE, direccion, T.telefono
from EntidadPublica E, Telefono T
where E.nombreE = t.nombreE
```

[image: * Yellow what I want to see]`

Comment: What is the logic for determining which of the 2 numbers to show?

Comment: Because then the information is shown in a grid on asp.net, but I can't repeat the company

Comment: In the real world there are plenty of companies sharing phone numbers because they're subsidiaries of a parent company using a shared call centre. Banks and insurance companies commonly do this. Will your schema cope with this?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning nono, is very small proyect

Comment: @DaleK I understand, it can really be random, no matter which one, with showing 1 already

Comment: @DaleK Yes!! , but i can put the answer as solved Idk why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select E.nombreE, E.direccion, min(T.telefono)
from EntidadPublica E join
     Telefono T
     on E.nombreE = t.nombreE
group by E.nombreE, E.direccion;
```

Comment: One little suggestion if you have empty strings  ...  min(nullif(T.telefono,''))